# How can I get every row from a Content Provider?

Tags: android, mysqli, android-contentprovider

How can I get every row from a content provider ? I tried to do this using `Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null, null, null)`
and then

```
String s;
if (c != null && c.moveToFirst()) 

        while (c.moveToNext()) 
                 s = c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("string"));

c.close();
```

but it didn't work.Instead of taking all the rows, it was taking only the last one, repeatedly, as many times as the rows-1 of my db.

Comment: "How can I get every row from a content provider ?" -- that depends on the implementation of the `ContentProvider`.

Comment: I have a class in which I have extended ContentProvider.

Comment: Then the problem is in your `ContentProvider` implementation, apparently. You need to implement your `ContentProvider` such that your desired `query()` call returns all rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting "rows-1" because your use of `moveToFirst()` followed by `moveToNext()` as the loop control causes you to skip the first row.

If you are seeing all rows of the DB with the same value for column "string", there is either a problem with the code that shows you "s" (which you didn't post) or your DB contains the same value for every row, or you have not implemented `query()` correctly in your `ContentProvider`.

You can also use [Cursor.getCount()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html#getCount()) to get the number of rows in the cursor.

This code works for me when run against a content provider backed by a DB:

```
        Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null, null, null);
        if (c != null) {
            while (c.moveToNext()) {
                String s = c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("name"));
                Log.i("Demo", s);
            }
            c.close();
        }
```

Comment: I think the problem is being generated inside the cursor iteration. I am using an arraylist and everytime before the loop starts again, I am adding the s value in the arraylist. I debuged it and the values of the arraylist are wrong  when the loop has ended. But the Logged values are fine !

Comment: The arraylist has only the last value repeated rows times

Comment: I found the mistake ! I was initialising the String out of the loop!